# Fungibility of ETFs traded in GBP and USD on the London Stock Exchange

Tags: united-kingdom, etf, vanguard, london-stock-exchange

I would like to buy some shares of [Vanguard FTSE All-World UCITS ETF (accumulating)](https://www.vanguard.co.uk/professional/product/etf/equity/9679/ftse-all-world-ucits-etf-usd-accumulating). According to the [fact sheet](https://www.vanguard.co.uk/professional/api/document/31355/gb), two tickers are available on the London Stock Exchange:

- [VWRP](https://www.londonstockexchange.com/stock/VWRP/vanguard/company-page) (traded in GBP)
- [VWRA](https://www.londonstockexchange.com/stock/VWRA/vanguard/company-page) (traded in USD)

VWRP and VWRA have the same ISIN (IE00BK5BQT80), but different SEDOL (BK5XT51 for VWRP, and BK5XTF1 for VWRA).

Are these two tickers completely fungible? If I use GBP to buy 100 shares of VWRP, will I be able to sell those 100 shares through VWRA and get USD?

Comment: Are you looking for a GBP/USD variant of Norbert's Gambit? I guess you'd at least need a broker that allows both GBP and USD balances.

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica No, Norbert's Gambit is not the reason I asked this question. I am merely curious about such situations for listings on the London Stock Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

No, if you hold VWRP you will have to sell them for GBP, and VWRA holdings would have to be sold for USD.

One curious case though: I used to hold XWSN which was the GBP priced version of XDWT (USD priced MSCI World Information Technology tracker).  When Xtrackers decided to close the XWSN units (which no longer exist), they were transmuted into the equivalent value of XDWT units (which does still exist) plus some small change.

Comment: Is the answer dependent on the stock brokerage firm used?

Comment: Not as far as I know; I'd be surprised.  Occurs to me there are some odd exceptions out there though.  For example BM Macro (a listed hedge fund) has both GBP and USD priced shares BHMG and BHMU, and investors have a monthly (IIRC) opportunity to convert between them.

Comment: ...I mean BH Macro, not BM Macro.